# How to add similar keys and their values in a dictionary in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary

I am writing a code which basically adds the values in similar items from both dictionaries, and prints rest items.

```
food = ["cheese pizza", "quiche","morning bun","gummy bear","tea cake"]

bakery_stock = {
    "almond croissant" : 12,
    "toffee cookie": 3,
    "morning bun": 1,
    "chocolate chunk cookie": 9,
    "tea cake": 25
}

new_di = dict.fromkeys(food, 1)
if new_di in bakery_stock:
     bakery_stock.update(new_di)
     print(bakery_stock)
```

Comment: `new_di in bakery_stock:` can't work. A dictionary can't be the key of another dictionary.

Comment: What are you trying to do with that condition?

Comment: What do you mean by similar items? What is the result you expect?

Comment: @Barmar I expect all items, and the sum of similar items. I.e. a = {'a':1}, b = {'a':1}. So I expect {'a': 2}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> food = ["cheese pizza", "quiche","morning bun","gummy bear","tea cake"]
>>> bakery_stock = {
...     "almond croissant" : 12,
...     "toffee cookie": 3,
...     "morning bun": 1,
...     "chocolate chunk cookie": 9,
...     "tea cake": 25
... }
>>> new_di = dict.fromkeys(food, 1)
>>> Counter(bakery_stock) + Counter(new_di)
Counter({'tea cake': 26, 'almond croissant': 12, 'chocolate chunk cookie': 9, 'toffee cookie': 3, 'morning bun': 2, 'cheese pizza': 1, 'quiche': 1, 'gummy bear': 1})
```

Comment: Is there a way to sum the items, without importing 'collections'?

Comment: @RahulPatel yes of course

Comment: Thanks, for this I was redirected to similar thread regarding this problem.